# Why do I have to call CFRelease after __bridge_transfer?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, clang-static-analyzer

```
CFArrayRef refAllPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
NSArray * arPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)(refAllPeople);
```

When I analyze it says potential memory leak.

Let me try to understand. refAllPeople have 1 ref count.

Then I do _*bridge*_transfer. That moves ownership to me. To be more exact, it has arPeople pointing to it and add the retain count by 1. Then the retain count is reduced by one because _*bridge*_transfer is equivalent with (__bridge) followed by CFRelease.

So,

Why the memory leak complaint?

Comment: I'm really sorry to see somebody with 3k+ rep tagging inappropriately with `xcode`.

Comment: @H2CO3 The `xcode` tag could be valid as this could be an issue with Xcode since his code looks right.

Comment: @fumoboy007 No, it can be an issue with either his code or with the static analyzer, none of which is Xcode.

Comment: I figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @JimThio and what was it?

Comment: @H2CO3 …the static analyzer is packaged into Xcode, so it falls under the `xcode` tag…

Comment: It's too embarrassing. There is no memory leak. The analyzer actually complain about something else, which I have since fixed. The error message is covered by something else (another warning or something i forget),

Comment: @fumoboy007 `llvm` is packaged into XCode too. Would you tag `xcode` any `llvm`-related question?

Comment: I tag most of my question as objective-c xcode4.5 however, in the future should I tag that just as objective-c?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella If you were using llvm via Xcode, then yes!

Comment: @fumoboy007 No, [it's a separate subproject of LLVM, and it has nothing to do with Xcode.](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) What is legitimately tagged with `xcode` is something like an autocompletion problem or an issue about Xcode project files, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, the `xcode` tag is intended from issues with the IDE itself.

Comment: @JimThio Better tag using the language (`objective-c`), maybe some descriptive tag about the smaller programming subtopic (`automatic-reference-counting`) and the tool you're using (`clang-static-analyzer`, does it exist?).

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I know that…my argument was that because he was using it through Xcode and it's packaged into Xcode and it's touted as a feature of Xcode, then the `xcode` tag can be used.

Comment: @fumoboy007 I see what you meant by that, but I'm afraid that's incorrect.

Comment: @fumoboy007 sorry man, but you'd better take a read to the `xcode` tag wiki

Comment: @GabrielePetronella "This tag should only be used for questions about the Xcode tool"? The static analyzer is a feature of "the Xcode tool", so I think it's appropriate to use `xcode`, no?

Comment: Saying that the clang static analyzer is a feature of XCode, is like saying that llvm, Objective-C, C++ and C are features of XCode, whereas all those pieces of technology just happen to be used inside XCode, which has nothing to do with their potential bugs

Comment: @GabrielePetronella No, I'm not saying "the clang static analyzer is a feature of Xcode"; I'm saying "the static analyzer is a feature of Xcode." Subtle but important difference. The compiler is also a feature of Xcode.

Comment: XCode comes bundled with those pieces of software, each one of which has its own tag and scope. Read the `this tag covers` section of the wiki, which is clear enough.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Ok, according to that section, this doesn't fall under `xcode`…but it should! =D=D

Comment: You can discuss about it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. But as long as the tag is defined like it is now, this kind of questions do not fall into it.

Comment: Where are the other answers? I was upvoting them too. @H2CO3? Where are you?

Comment: @JimThio My answer was wrong, so I deleted it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is correct. `__bridge_transfer` will take `refAllPeople` back to the world of `NSObject` where `ARC` operates and you don't have to explicitly call `CFRelease`.

I believe it's a static analyser mistake.

From the docs (thanks Carl)

> (__bridge_transfer T) op casts the operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a retainable object pointer type. ARC will release the value at the end of the enclosing full-expression, subject to the usual optimizations on local values.

Comment: From the clang docs: "(__bridge_transfer T) op casts the operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a retainable object pointer type. ARC will release the value at the end of the enclosing full-expression, subject to the usual optimizations on local values." that implies the opposite of what you're saying though.

Comment: Then I think my initial answer holds. Sorry, it's late here ^^

Comment: @GabrielePetronella No worries, better late than never. +1 for the right answer. I just can't get my head around ARC.

Comment: I know that feeling, every time I need to mix CF and NS objects I got shivers

Comment: Hei it sens shivers down on my spine too.

Answer (score 1):

It's embarrassing. There is no memory leak :). Somehow I misread the error message and think all blue things means memory leak.

I am glad that my understanding of bridge_transfer is correct and I hope it's useful for everyone.

+1 for others that have answered this :)